# child element border positioned over parent border

Tags: html, css

I have a simple set of links at the top of a page with a black border underneath. The active link should show a white border underneath. This border should sit directly over the black border.

I am unable to change the HTML at this stage, only the styling.

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/grimmus/8E4D5/

```
<div class="c-landing-pg-tabs-container">
    <div class="c-landing-pg-tabs paymentsLeft">
        <div><a href="#self" class="active-tab">Payments</a></div>
        <div><a href="#self">Inquiries</a></div>
        <div><a href="#self">Trade</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am having difficulty getting it positioned over the black border. I can change the display to inline-block, increase the height of the A element, but it sits underneath all the time. Tried also to change to position:relative and nudge it down a bit. It seems some sort of z-index might work but not sure if it's possible because all elements are contained within the same parent.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the overflow:hidden from .c-landing-pg-tabs-container and add padding-bottom: 12px; to .c-landing-pg-tabs a.active-tab. The new rules will look like this:

```
.c-landing-pg-tabs-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 41px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 240px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #282828;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.c-landing-pg-tabs a.active-tab {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Here's your modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sc5pB/